# NPM install permission denied error using root user

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, frontend, npm-install

So I've made a fresh installation of npm/node on my local machine using NVM using root user and everything looks fine, now my issue is when I tried to install using **npm install --unsafe-perm -verbose** command on my project folder error displays in my terminal.

```
npm verb stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b 0.0.7 https://github.com/Mango/emitter.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-28a98ad9
npm verb stack fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-28a98ad9': Permission denied
npm verb stack 
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:282:12)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:957:16)
npm verb stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:378:11)
npm verb stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm verb stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:598:12)
npm verb cwd /web/nbltv
npm verb Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
npm verb argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-per" "-verbose"
npm verb node v10.1.0
npm verb npm  v5.6.0
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b 0.0.7 https://github.com/Mango/emitter.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-28a98ad9
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-28a98ad9': Permission denied
npm ERR! 
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-20T01_36_33_496Z-debug.log
```

**NPM version - 5.6
NODE version - 10.1**

Any help would be much appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Chown** down your node_modules & do not run as sudo.

You should always have ownership of the `.npm` directory as *NPM will refuse installing native modules with sudo* as this can be a security risk.

Try `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm` and see if this would work. (or `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.nvm` if you're using nvm)

Or [reinstall with a node version manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation) without root as recommended in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-one-reinstall-with-a-node-version-manager):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: This question is unrelated to docker (They're on local machine). This is not applicable to your scenario, @Rumen Rumenov. Perhaps this could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543874/5037430

If you cannot find the question you're looking for, feel free to raise another one and we are happy to help.

Answer (score 9):

Creating a new global storage in your user space is the recommended way of preventing this error. Don't use sudo or change ownership of locations.

```
$ mkdir ~/.npm-global
$ npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
$ export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
$ source ~/.profile
```

However, since you're using npm 5.6, this might be more relevant to you:

> **npx: an alternative to running global commands**
>
> If you are using npm version 5.2 or greater, you may want to consider npx as an alternative way to run global commands, especially if you only need a command occasionally. For more information, see [this article about npx](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b).

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: I get this error if I run those commands: 

nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/home/denver/.npm-global"
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v10.24.1 --silent` to unset it.

Answer (score 1):

@U-ways answer is very good but for people who use nvm 
rather than:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

do

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.nvm
```

this works form me

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```