# Docker node js issues: sudo not found

Tags: docker, npm, azure-devops

I am having issues with building my docker file with Azure DevOps.

Here is a copy of my docker file:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy app
COPY . .

# install packages
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    git \
    python \
    make \
    g++ \
    && sudo npm@latest -g wait-on concurrently truffle  \
    && npm install \
    && apk del build-dependencies \ 
    && truffle compile --all

# Expose the right ports, the commands below are irrelevant when using a docker-compose file.
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "server”]
```

it was working recently now I am getting the following error message:

> sudo not found.

What is the cause of this `sudo not found` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use sudo. Just drop that from the command. That image is already running as root by default - there's no reason for it.

```
TJs-MacBook-Pro:~ tj$ docker run node:10-alpine whoami
root
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. when I take sudo out , I get permission errors with the npm install package i.e EACESS permission denied do you know a way around this?

Comment: @SamuelDare Unsure. Why don't you run a `node:10-alpine` image directly, and run the commands line by line to see what is breaking and why it's doing so.

Although - I'd also just recommend using an official node image rather than set this up yourself.